# PHP not printing MongoID from array after array filter

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I've recently been having some issues with printing my mongoID from an array after performing an array_filter on the array:

```
  $array = array_filter($array);
  $array = array_slice($array, 0, 3, true);
```

This used to be fine and work without the array_filter, now the array contains:

```
Array ( [3] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b0facace2350981c000029 ) [4] => MongoId Object ( [$id] => 57b0fafcce2350981c00002b ) )
```

However printing out the ID now fails or does not loop:

```
  $length = count($array);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
  $id = $array[$i]->{'$id'};
  echo $id;
  }
```

Again this all used to work but after filtering to remove null elements, however it now seems to not iterate over the array correctly, but this may be another issue. Any help solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at the keys of your posted array and then look at your for loop and what you do there :P

Comment: you mean because my keys start at 3 after filtering? so i should find a way to loop over it for each item rather than using the length of the array?

Comment: Exactly. And because your preserve the keys in `array_slice()` they will still start at 3 :) So you could use a foreach loop or get the keys from the array with `array_keys()` and then access the keys with the counter variable from the for loop and the keys for the array index.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help actually just got it working, if you post this as an answer i'll credit you.

Comment: You can self-answer your question if your want, since you now figured it out and got it working. Also note that always when you're debugging code you should turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and then you would have got a warning for those undefined indexes you tried to access.

Comment: ah solid advice! thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error was the preservation of the keys in the array due to array_slice after using array_filter to remove null elements. This meant using the array length to iterate over it did not work and instead a foreach loop was required to ensure that it would iterate over all the elements in the array :

```
foreach ($array as &$value)
{
}
```

Thanks @Rizier123